# Display registered user's list using v-for from Laravel 9

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I'm studying Vuejs composition API and Laravel.
This app has Auth.
I can successfully CRUD data using Axios which 'companies' table.

I'm trying to go next step that I would like to add Vuejs v-for dropdown-lists which disiplay Laravel's registered users name.
I wrote this code but this won't fetch data.
Could you teach me how to fetch user name please?

> User Contoroller

```
class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        return UserResource::collection(User::all());
    }
}
```

> companies.js

```
import { ref } from 'vue'
import axios from "axios"; 
import { useRouter } from 'vue-router';

export default function useCompanies() {
    const companies = ref([])
    const company = ref([])
    const router = useRouter()
    const errors = ref('')
    
    const users = ref([])    
    const getUsers = async () => {
        let response2 = await axios.get('/api/users')
        users.value= response2.data.data;
    }
       
    const getCompanies = async () => {
        let response = await axios.get('/api/companies')
        companies.value = response.data.data;
    }
```

> CompaniesCreate.vue

```
<template>
        v-for list
        
<select v-model="selectedItem">
      <option 
        v-for="user in users" 
        :value="user.id" 
        :key="user.id"
      >
        {{ user.name }}
      </option>
    </select>

</template>


const registeredUser = axios.get('/users')
.then((response2)=>{
 this.data = response2.data.data
 })
                     
const form = reactive({
    selectedItem: registeredUser,
})
                     
import { ref, computed, reactive, onMounted } from "vue";
import useCompanies from "@/composables/companies"; 

const { errors, storeCompany } = useCompanies()
const saveCompany = async () => {
    await storeCompany({ ...form });
}
```

> api.php

```
Route::apiResource('companies', CompanyController::class);
Route::apiResource('users', UserController::class);
```